# Trying to connect to mysql database from virtual machine (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, virtual

I'm trying to show the data form the empleados table. The table is inside the ucol database, which is in an Ubuntu virtual machine. I already configured the host-only network, it pings both ways. But when I run the program it catches an exception

```
static final String controlador = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String direccion = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.73:3306/ucol";
static final String usuario = "user";
static final String clave = "pass";  

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conexion = null;
   Statement consulta = null;
   String sql;

   int id;
   String nombre;
   String apellidos;
   double salarios;

   try {
       System.out.println("Connecting...");
       Class.forName(controlador);
       conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(direccion, usuario, clave);
       consulta = conexion.createStatement();
       System.out.println("Connection done.");


       sql = "SELECT id, nombre, apellidos, salarios FROM empleados;";
       ResultSet resultado = consulta.executeQuery(sql);

       while(resultado.next()) {
           id = resultado.getInt("id");
           nombre = resultado.getString("nombre");
           apellidos = resultado.getString("apellidos");
           salarios = resultado.getInt("salarios");

           System.out.println("\nID: " + id 
                   + "\tNombre: " + nombre 
                   + "\tApellido: " + apellidos
                   + "\tSalarios: " + salarios);
       }

       resultado.close();
       consulta.close();
       conexion.close();
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
       System.err.println("Error at showing: " + e.toString());
   }
   finally {
       try {
           if(consulta != null)
               consulta.close();
           if(conexion != null)
               conexion.close();
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Error at closing: " + e.toString());
       }
   }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Connecting
Error at showing: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection timed out: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at Consulta.main(Consulta.java:37)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 2 ms ago.
```

Here's how it shows the ifconfig on the virtual machine:

```
eth0     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         Direc. inet: 192.168.1.73 Difus.192.168.1.55 Másc.: 255.255.255.0
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: First of all, add MySQL port to connection string and check if it's opened on VM. Standard one is 3306.
`direccion = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.73:3306/ucol"`

Comment: Done. Throws the same exception.

Comment: And you are able to login to the mysql via a terminal and show that particular table?

Comment: Yes, I access using the mysql user and the password and it works from the virtual machine and everything works fine. Should the "user" string be the Ubuntu user or the Mysql user? Either way I change it for both cases and still throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I stopped the ufw service at the virtual machine.

```
sudo service ufw stop
```